# Clearing cache and killing background services in android

Tags: android, clear-cache

I am working on a project in which user will be able to clear the cache and clean up the ram memory. I want to clear the mobile cache and also kill the background services like facebook service, or other applications services from my application. Now I know many people will mark it as duplicate but that is not correct because I have been searching this solution for 1 week and could not found any good solution. I am getting the total cache memory but I cannot clear it through my application. So please help me out in this problem. I have read and tried many other codes but could not find the solution. Instead of marking it duplicate, any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Show us some code! With what exactly are you having trouble? If you are just asking us "how to do X and Y" then you are in the wrong place. We are here to help you fix errors and problems, not to do your work for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905938/how-to-clear-other-applications-cache-from-another-android-app-in-marshmallow?rq=1

Sir this is from where I am using help. Now I am really really confuse to call IPacakgeDataObserver class from my MainActivity.

Comment: now I can access this interface. But again Cache is same, nothing removed from the cache. I have tried different codes but not getting success.